# Adding an HTML element for each month on a Calendar Events' list in PugJS

Tags: pug

I am building an "Events List" in PugJS and I am going through each event and I would like to add a html element, like this, for each month: `<div data-month="October">`. After listing the events for that month, I have to close that `</div>` and start a new one for the next month.

On the backend I am just having a `title` field and a `date` field for each event. I would like to make this without having to add an extra field, to select again a "month", which could bring bugs in case the selected month is not the same as on the `date` field (to be able to list the events, if does it makes sense)?

For now, I am on this step:

```js
each event in calendar_events
  - var str = event.primary.event_date // 2021-10-22
  - var separator = '-';
  - var month = str.split(separator, 2).pop(); // 10

  while (month === '10')
    - month = 'October'

    //- I need to add here a <div data-month="October">

    h2=event.primary.event_title[0].text
    p=event.primary.event_date

    //- After showing all the items,
    //- I need to close that </div>

  while (month === '11')

    - month = 'November'
    //- I need to add here a <div data-month="November">

    h2=event.primary.event_title[0].text
    p=event.primary.event_date

    //- After showing all the items,
    //- I need to close that </div>
```

The problem is that I get a duplicate `<div data-month="October">` for each entry in October, because I have to start the iteration on the first line: `each event in calendar_events`.

I'll leave here this CodePen link, with the html version, because I think you guys can get the main idea of my question: https://codepen.io/ositaka/pen/abwjrPe

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I have to start the iteration on the first line"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is already sorted by the date, try:

```
- 
  const calendar_events = [{ pr: { ed: "2021-10-22", et: [ { text: "xx"} ]}},
   { pr: { ed: "2021-10-23", et: [ { text: "yy"} ]}},
   { pr: { ed: "2021-12-25", et: [ { text: "Xmas"} ]}},
   { pr: { ed: "2022-01-01", et: [ { text: "New Year's Day"} ]}} ];
  const getYear = event => event.pr.ed.split("-")[0];
  const getMonth = event => Number(event.pr.ed.split("-", 2).pop());
  const getDay = event => event.pr.ed.split("-")[2];
  const months = ['dummy','jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec'];

  let current = { year: getYear(calendar_events[0]), month: 0 };
  const incCurrent = () => { 
    if (current.month==12) {
      current.month = 1; current.year++;
    } else current.month++;
  }
- for (let i=0; i<calendar_events.length; i++) {
-   let month = getMonth(calendar_events[i]);
-   if (current.month != month) {
-     while (current.month != month) incCurrent();
  h3 New Month #{months[month]}-#{getYear(calendar_events[i])}
  .events__group(data-month=months[month])
    p #{getDay(calendar_events[i])} - #{calendar_events[i].pr.et[0].text}
    while i<calendar_events.length-1 && getMonth(calendar_events[i+1])==current.month
      - i++;
      p #{getDay(calendar_events[i])} - #{calendar_events[i].pr.et[0].text}
-   }
- }
```

The output:

```
<h3>New Month oct-2021</h3>
<div class="events__group" data-month="oct">
  <p>22 - xx</p>
  <p>23 - yy</p>
</div>
<h3>New Month dec-2021</h3>
<div class="events__group" data-month="dec">
  <p>25 - Xmas</p>
</div>
<h3>New Month jan-2022</h3>
<div class="events__group" data-month="jan">
  <p>01 - New Year's Day</p>
</div>
```

Notes about the pug code:

- I hardcoded some test data
- I added a helper function `getMonth` to reduce the verbosity to extract the month value that is buried deep in your data object
- There is a confusing mixture of true Javascript (lines or blocks beginning with -) which are not very indent sensitive, and pug's pseudo Javascript which are indent sensitive.
- The data must be valid to avoid endless `while` loops. Example 2021-13-01 will get you into trouble.

Comment: I was able to make it working, but is there one little detail. I've to sort the dates also by year (first). I've been trying to extend your code, but is not totally working. This is what I have so far: https://codepen.io/ositaka/pen/VwWVEWE?editors=1010 

I've added a `getYear()` function and I think I have to imitate what you have done to check the `while (currentMonth != month)`, but for each Year. 

I think I've to add an extra `while` loop for the Year, before the `while` loop for the months: `while i<calendar_events.length-1 && getMonth(calendar_events[i+1])==currentMonth`

Comment: @NunoMarques I have updated the answer. `current` is changed to an object containing year and month, and an increment function is added to move `current` ahead by one month each time. Test data has been modified to span multi-years. Hope this is what you need.

Comment: is it working :) Thank you very much! As a side note, I've added the following code on my app.js file, to "sort" the events by date, otherwise it wouldn't work. Here is the code if somebody also needs it: calendar_events.sort(function (a, b) {     return new Date(a.event_date) - new Date(b.event_date)   })

Comment: Everyone can also check this code working in Vanilla JS, here: https://codepen.io/ositaka/pen/mdwQagj?editors=1111

Comment: @NunoMarques Are you doing pug on the server or in the client?

Comment: I am doing it server-side rendering, with ExpressJS and Prismic as headless CMS. I am using the pug as the template engine with the `data` coming from Prismic.